# Qt connect signal with another class method

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have class

```
class Files : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Files();
    ~Files();

public slots:
    void saveFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui);
    void openFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui);
    void checkOpenFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui);
    void newFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui);
    void checkNewFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui);
    void closeFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui);
};
```

and i want to connect button placed in MainWindow class with slot `void newFile(Ui::MainWindow * ui)` of `Files` class

i tried

```
files = new Files;
    //files->newFile(ui); works as it should
    connect(ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), files, SLOT(closeFile(ui)));
```

and I have message:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot Files::closeFile(ui) in ../qt/src/core/mainwindow.cpp:16
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'actionExit')
```

How should i connect `ui->actionExit` with `Files::closeFile(ui)` slot the right way?

Comment: Stop using the old / obsolete / slow string comparison based and only run-time checked `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros. Use the modern compile-time checked and faster pointer to member function based `connect()` syntax instead.

Comment: Something along these lines: `connect(ui->actionExit, &QAction::triggered, [=]() { files->closeFile(ui); });` . If for some reason you insist on old-style syntax, then you need a slot with the signature matching that of the trigger - that is, you won't be able to pass `Ui::MainWindow*` to the slot. It would probably be easiest in this case to pass it to `Files` constructor instead, and store it in a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are attempting to connect signal and slot which are not compatible with each other: `closeFile` slot requires a parameter of `Ui::MainWindow *` type but the signal which you are attempting to connect to it has no parameters.

Do you really need `closeFile` to take a pointer to `Ui::MainWindow`? Can you instead make this and other slots take no parameters? If you really need to access `Ui::MainWindow` from inside methods/slots within `Files`, you can just create a setter to pass the pointer to `Ui::MainWindow` to `Files` and use that pointer in slots which themselves won't take any parameters.

Second, you are trying to use old, obsolete and slow method of setting up connections between signals and slots. This method is not only bad because it's slow but it is also bad because it only shows you errors during runtime i.e. when you compile and launch your app. If you used [pointer to member function based connection syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html), it would refuse to compile should you try to connect incompatible signals and slots. It is much better this way because you can see and fix the errors early.